# How Does the any Method Work in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, jvm-languages

I came across this bit of code:

```
n = args[0] as Long
[*n..1, n].any{ println ' '*it + '*'*(n - ~n - it*2) }
```

It's used for printing a tree form of structure. Like this:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
    *
```

(for `n`=4)

1. How does the code `[*n..1,n]` produce `[4, 3, 2, 1, 4]`?
2. How does `any` method works here? The [Doc](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#any%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) doesn't help me much. What is a predictive that can be passed to `any`(as mentioned in [Doc](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#any%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)'s)?

Whats the use of `any` and how its handled in this case?

Comment: @DownVoter : why a downvote? `any` wrong in this question ;) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Q1a: `*` "unpacks" an array. `..` creates a range. `[]` creates a collection.
Q1b: `*n..1` unpacks [4,3,2,1] into its individual parts.
Q1c: `[4,3,2,1,n]` == `[4,3,2,1,4]`

Q2: I don't know why `any` was used here; `each` works just as well, and makes more sense in context. `any` *does* loop over the connection, so the `println` side-effect functions as intended.

Normally `any` would be used to determine if any collection elements met a criteria, for example:

```
[*n..1,n].any { it > 10 } // Returns false, no elements are > 10
[*n..1,n].any { it == 3 } // Returns true, because at least one element is 3
```

The last statement of the closure is used to determine if each item meets the criteria. `println` returns null, so `any` will return false. The value is unused and discarded.

The only reason I can think of that someone might have used `any` is to avoid seeing the return value of `each` in the console. `each` returns the original collection.

Comment: Other reason to have used `.any` is to use the least number of characters in Code Golf Competition [How to print out a Christmas tree of height N](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4244)

Answer (score 3):

1) `n..1` is called a range literal, it creates a [`groovy.lang.Range`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Range.html) object that decrements by 1 from `n` to `1`. This is then merged into the surrounding list context using the "[Spread operator](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-spread-operator.html) (*)"

2) the [`any`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#any%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method is defined in [`DefaultGroovyMethods`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html) and it is a predicate function that returns true if an element in a collection satisfies the supplied predicate closure. In this example, the code doesn't check the return value, so original other could have produced the same output using an [`each`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#each%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) call instead.